# как вывести на консоль общее количество итераций? c#

Tags: c#, циклы

Например. перебираются в цикле for числа,от одного до "КАКОГО ТО РАНДОМНОГО ЧИСЛА". как сделать так,чтобы на консоли было только  "КАКОЕ ТО РАНДОМНОЕ ЧИСЛО",а не все эти числа?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(КАКОЕ_ТО_РАНДОМНОЕ_ЧИСЛО);`

Comment: Непонятно в чем проблема. Покажите пример цикла и ожидаемого вывода в консоли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как насчет такого:

```
int number = 0;
for(var i=0; i<YourNumber; i++)
{
    number = array[i];
}
Console.Writeline(number);
```

Если вам нужно число, которое было в последней итерации цикла, то я вам дал решение.

Comment: Чем это отличается от `Console.Writeline(array[array.Length-1]);` ?

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, что хочет задавший вопрос. Я так понял, он каким-то особым образом идет по массиву, и ему нужно вывести то, что было в конце. Сейчас немного отредактирую ответ.

Comment: имхо, вопрос задан так, что попытка дать на него ответ - чистое гадание

Comment: Да. Я отметил вопрос тревогой "Непонятный", можете присоединиться. Что-то сомневаюсь, что задавший таки закроет или переформулирует вопрос.

Comment: Да,всё именно так,спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Вы правильно меня поняли)

Comment: Можете плюсануть ответу,  раз правильно понял.